# Remember preferred tab (relevance/newest/votes/active) after entering search term

Tags: feature-request, search

Go to Stack Overflow, enter a search term. You get a choice of four tabs: relevance/newest/votes/active.

Most people seem to have a preference. For myself: every single time I click "newest".

I have to do this, a hundred times a week!

It would be really great if SO could preference this.

For those who don't like the idea, it would be completely invisible -- no change in how the site works -- to any folks who did not bother with the issue.

By the way, if **you simply click** "Questions", you do indeed get "Newest" tab by default. So, it's a shame that **when you search**, you get "Relevance" tab by default.

Comment: I appreciate the downvote feedback, but could you tell me why?  It's really hard to see why you would object to this being *a preference*.  (Note that of course you would not be affected *in any way* if this was added as a preference; you could completely ignore it if preferred.)

Comment: What's the connection between search inside of SO itself, and *make money from suckclicks*?

Comment: @JoeBlow Disagreement with your feature-request. That's the traditional folklore on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: hey @πάνταῥεῖ -  yes, I understand that: I'm wondering WHY those folks disagree.

Comment: The sentence you just removed was potentally part of it.....

Comment: @JoeBlow Most probably because there are more important things to fix than save you from a single click.

Comment: I agree with you, especially seeing that 'relevance' almost never gives me the results I want.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the most annoying part is that if you search from the search results page itself, with one of the other 'tabs' open, it still gets reset to 'Relevance'

Comment: hi @Tunaki, I deleted the irrelevant sentence.  Let's stick to the point.  (You don't usually downvote here because you "don't like the writing"; up or down vote means you do or do not support the proposal.)  In any event I am curious to know why two - no three - folks are opposed, cheers! (Incidentally - I would rather discuss this over, say, a Saint-Estèphe! :) )

Comment: hi @πάνταῥεῖ  - "single clicks" don't work like that: on web sites single clicks, especially at the *top of the hierarchy*, are incredibly important; Amazon spend millions on researching, and make or lose 100s of millions, based on one click either way in the chain.  I have had to do this click, maybe, *20,000 times*. It's amazingly annoying.

Comment: @JoeBlow Well, I have to admit I rarely use the intrinsic SO search but google (which usually yields the best relevance).

Comment: I've been annoyed by this for ages as well. It doesn't really have to remember as far as I'm concerned. `sort:newest` or `order:newest` is also fine by me (although remembering would be *better*).